# Email forwarding with MX records

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

I have a domain example.com and mail is handled by outlook.com. Now I want to backup a copy of all mails coming to example.com in my local server using mx records before forwarding it to outlook.com. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not using MX records.  You'll need an auto-forward rule on your MTA that forwards user@example.com on to user@outlook.com while delivering a copy locally.  How you do this is MTA dependent.  Google is your friend.

Comment: can i use postfix to store a copy of mail locally and forward to google apps?

Comment: Google is your friend...  "postfix store local copy and forward"